# On an island of 20 wizards, every set of three cast a spell on another. Show that there must be a wizard targeted by at least 9 wizards.

Tags: combinatorics

> Twenty wizards meet on an island. Every set of 3 wizards cast a spell together on another wizard. Show that there must be a wizard who had been targeted by at least 9 wizards. (Each wizard can be in multiple groups.)

Comment: Have you computed how many sets of $3$ there are?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $d_i$ be the number of wizards that take action on wizard $W_i$. Then by double counting we have $${20\choose 3} =\sum {d_i\choose 3} \leq 20{d\choose 3}$$

where $d$ maximal $d_i$. If $d\leq 8$ we get $$ 19\cdot 18 \leq 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\implies 57\leq 56$$ A contradiction.

Comment: Let's consider this 20 wizards as vertices on an undirected graph. If $\exists v \text{ s.t. } deg(v) < 19$, i.e., the graph is not completely connected, then $\exists w, \text { s.t. } vw$ is not an edge. Then if we consider any other vertex $x$ and the set $\{v,w,x\}$, then this set of wizards violates the asked condition of any $3$ set of wizards shooting at each other. Essentially, how can we have a graph that is not completely connected satisfying the given condition? Thanks.